# Find the number of appearances of a keyword found in a list in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter
import csv
import pandas as pd
```

**Obtain data from CSV:**

```
address = 'filepath'
example = pd.read_csv(address)
review_column = example.Reviews
```

**Data obtained and to be inserted into the list**

```
reviews = []
for w in review_column:
    reviews.append(w)
```

**Further enhancement to the data in the list by removing stopwords and punctuation.**

```
reviews = [word for word in reviews if word not in stopwords.words('english')] 
reviews = [word for word in reviews if word not in punctuation]     
#reviews = [word_tokenize(i) for i in reviews]
```

**Obtain data from CSV**

```
address = 'filepath'
example = pd.read_csv(address)
keywords_column = example.Keywords
```

**Insert Data into List**

```
keywords = []
for w in keywords_column:
    keywords.append(w)

#keywords_tokenised = []
#keywords_tokenised = [word_tokenize(i) for i in keywords]

frequency_list = []
frequency = 0 
for word in keywords:    
    if word == reviews:
        frequency += 1
        frequency_list.append((word,frequency))
    else:
        frequency_list.append((word,frequency))
print(frequency_list)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  What part of this isn't working?

Comment: instead of count getting update for same key, new keys are getting added. is that your question?